# Laravel Code Stops Prematurely After Fetching Large Data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel command that fetches very large JSON data from a URL. The data is so large that I have to change the default Http `timeout` so that the request does not timeout before the complete data is fetched.

I have also increased the memory_limit (in my php-memory-limits.ini file) to `3G` (3 Gigabytes) because the script exceeded the memory limit set in my PHP configuration file.

```
$response = Http::timeout(2000)->get($url);

if ($response->successful()) {
    $this->info("Data fetch complete. Proceeding with next steps"); // Code execution stops here

    $collect = $response->collect();
    $chunks = $collect->chunk(100);

    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        ProcessData::dispatch($chunk);
    }
}
```

Problem:

The code seems to be fetching the JSON data successfully (after a long time) but then it just stops executing the rest of the code once the data is fetched. As you can see, I have a queued job that is supposed to handle the fetched data but it does not proceed to that stage so I’m a bit confused as to what might be the problem. And how to solve it.

I have tried different approaches to solving the issue like `set_time_limit(0)` and `max_execution_time = 0` (php.ini) and none of these seem to be solving the problem.

Comment: What server are you using? Do you know the size of that JSON? I think you should use another language to get the data and put it in a file, and then the job should read that file. Or, let the other language create more than 1 JSON file, with parts, so it is still not a giant JSON

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the immediate processing of queued jobs, you can utilize the `dispatchSync` method instead of `dispatch`. Doing so will get the job executed immediately instead of being added to the queue.

```
$response = Http::timeout(2000)->get($url);

if ($response->successful()) {
    $this->info("Data fetch complete. Proceeding with next steps");

    $collect = $response->collect();
    $chunks = $collect->chunk(100);

    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        ProcessData::dispatchSync($chunk);
    }
}
```